# Darkmode toggle white flash before page switches

Tags: javascript

When darkmode is enabled and I switch from one page to another there is a white flash for few milliseconds. My understanding is that it's because the page is being parsed before js ?

Any idea on how I can fix that ?

```
let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
const sun = document.getElementById("sun");
const moon = document.getElementById("moon");
const darkModeToggle = document.querySelector("#dark-mode-toggle");

const enableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.add("darkmode");

  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enabled");
};

const disableDarkMode = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");

  localStorage.setItem("darkMode", null);
};

if (darkMode === "enabled") {
  enableDarkMode();
}

darkModeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");

  if (darkMode !== "enabled") {
    enableDarkMode();
    sun.style.display = "inline";
    moon.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    disableDarkMode();
    sun.style.display = "none";
    moon.style.display = "inline";
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you'de be better of to just use `@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){}` instead of implementing it yourself? Since the page is white by default until the style and script is loaded, this will be rather hard to do consistently otherwise.

Comment: Unfurtunatley, not I want light mode as default, I'm thinking if there is anyway of making darkmode script load before the dom ? maybe that would work

Comment: For Page to Page loading, you can't beat making your website into a SPA.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA   React apps are normally SPA, but you can easily role your own.

Comment: @somethinghere using the prefers-color-scheme as the default is fine, but providing the option to toggle is always preferred. I like some apps with dark mode, but not all, especially ones that were not well designed.

Comment: When does the code you have shown us execute? Is it inline in the document, or an external script?

Comment: @CBroe external script at the bottom of the body document

Comment: @Keith I'm not quite at that level yet.

Comment: _"external script at the bottom of the body document"_ - okay, clear then how that is problematic, no? My suggestion would be that you modify your CSS so that dark mode styles get applied based on `html` getting the class, not `body` - and then have `<script>document.documentElement.className = (localStorage.getItem("darkMode") == 'enabled') ? 'darkmode' : '';</script>` as the very first thing in your `head` element. (The rest of it can stay where it is, only the `enableDarkMode();` call wrapped in that if should be removed.)

Comment: (Or, if your `html` element could have classes set initially already, that must not be lost during this, `document.documentElement.className += (...) ? ' darkmode' : ''`)